# How do we know that field produced by contact forces is time invariant?

Tags: field-theory

I don't get the fact that action reaction forces act at the same time(Newton's third law). If this is so then it shouldn't be true for time invariant field since they would reach from source to sink and likewise the sink will produce field which will then reach the source.

Answer (score 0):

You're confused with the field lines concept I guess. For example, in electrostatics, field lines are only relevant when you place a *third* charge somewhere in space near a 2 charge system. The field line covers the directions where a force by 2 charges would be when there's a third charge placed in that region.

Newton's third law has mentions in a lot of places in physics that actually sounds practical. Take, for instance, Newton's gravitational law and the Coulomb's law.

In the former, the force of gravity exists between *two* masses. This interaction force is between two charges, i.e. both charges feel forces from the other one, and the same instant. Likewise for Coulomb's law.